# VBA create IE object from ProcessID

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

To interact VBA with IE in Private mode, I use this code:

```
Dim sh As Object, oWin As Object
Dim wss As Object
Dim IE as Object

Set wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

wss.exec "%ProgramFiles%/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe -private"
''You will probably need a delay here
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

For Each oWin In sh.Windows
    If TypeName(oWin.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
        Set IE = oWin
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The problem is that above code get first opened IE window as object not one executed by .exec command.

So, I think it's better I use below code instead:

```
lPID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -private", vbNormalFocus)
```

But I don't know how to create IE object using Process ID (lPID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and I tested it. Work!

```
Dim sh As Object, oWin As Object
Dim wss As Object
Dim IE as Object

Set wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

wss.exec "%ProgramFiles%/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe -private"
''You will probably need a delay here
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

' Get last opened shell
Set IE = sh.Windows(sh.Windows.Count - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
#End If

Function getPrivateIE() As Object
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWnd As Long
    #End If

    Shell "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -private", vbNormalFocus

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

    hWnd = GetForegroundWindow()

    Dim oWin As Object

    For Each oWin In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If oWin.hWnd = hWnd Then
            Set getPrivateIE = oWin
            Debug.Print "Success"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: If there are multiple "inPrivate" opened windows, this can't get correct window as IE object.

Comment: @AliM67 Sorry about the initial answer.  I was in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're genius.