# Strange Behavior: Variant Set to Object without using Set

Tags: vba

While writting my anser to [VBA create IE object from ProcessID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317158/9912714), I came accross this strange behavior.  Notice that even though the `win` variable isn't set to the `IWebBrowser` object it is still `Set` to the `IWebBrowser` object.

Am I missing something???  Will Matt, Continium, ThunderFrames...someboby please `Set me Straight` on this?

```
Sub WierdBehavior()
    Dim win As Variant
    win = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    Debug.Print IsObject(win), TypeName(win)
End Sub
```

[image: Immediate Window Screenshot]

Comment: Interesting, but unlikely to be of much significance one way or the other. Variants are pointers under the hood. There is something about this particular object that allows for it to be assigned to `win` without the keyword `set`. Perhaps this object somehow has itself as a default property?

Comment: Possibly more connected to assigning win to a property of the shell object - with late-bound code there's no way to know what type of object that would be, so the compiler doesn't flag it up?  edit: if you drop the `.Windows` then Set is required

Comment: If you insert `Set` before the assignment, the type of `win` becomes `IShellWindows`, rather than `IWebBrowser2`, so the latter must be the default property of the former.

Comment: "with late-bound code there's no way to know what type of object that would be" - I meant "what type of object or non-object"...

Comment: `Whenever you assign a reference to an object variable, the assignment uses the Set keyword. If you do not use Set, Visual Basic will try to find a default property of the object variable and set that default property.` https://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/dist-obj/winclnt/winvbpro.html

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: @SiddharthRout Could you please post an answer so that I can accept it and close the question?

Comment: I believe @JohnColeman is the best person for this :) Let him post an answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman  Siddharth Rout found the reference to answer based off of your comment.  Could you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @TinMan Maybe wait another day or so and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). That if the right-hand side of an assignment is an object and the left-hand side doesn't use `Set` then the assignment defaults to the assignment of the default property of the object (if any) is fairly standard. You see it with range objects all the time (where the default property is `Value`). What is new about your question is that the default value can itself be an object, something which I didn't know. We may have given you the idea, but you carried it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to replicate the behavoir by having a class return an Interface as its Default Memeber.  Credit John Coleman and Tim Williams for giving me the idea.
Interface: IClass

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "IClass"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Public Property Get getFoo() As Object
End Property
```

Class: Class2

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class2"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Implements IClass
Private MyCollection As New Collection
Private Property Get IClass_getFoo() As Object
    Set Class1_getFoo = MyCollection
End Property

Public Function getInterface() As IClass
Attribute getInterface.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set getInterface = Me
End Function
```

### Test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim win As Variant
    Dim MyClass2 As New Class2
    win = MyClass2
    Debug.Print IsObject(win), TypeName(win)
End Sub
```

### Results

### [image: Immediate Window Screen Shot]